# Overlay library for iOS?

Tags: iphone, overlay

there's an open-source library generating nice overlays for iPhone/iPad, but I don't find it any more... Does anyone know which one I mean?
**EDIT:** I'm looking for a gray, semi-transparent overlay view e.g. in the middle of the screen. I'd like to show information there while scrolling happens. As soon as scrolling ends, the overlay would disappear.

Comment: You question is a bit vague. What kind of overlays are you looking for?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe you are talking about MBProgressHUD?

https://github.com/jdg/MBProgressHUD

Answer (score 2):

I use [ATMHud](https://github.com/atomton/ATMHud). It looks like [this](http://dlinsin.github.com/2011/03/24/ATMHud.html).